# Как скачивать с файлообменника через тор?

Tags: cors, tor

Собственно проблема: файлообменник предоставляет ссылку для текущего ip (с которого получена ссылка), но ссылка принадлежит другому домену. Соответственно, при попытке скачать по ней, для нового домена получается другая цепочка и другой ip-адрес.

При скачивании через ajax-запрос (fetch) ip-адрес верный, но cors-заголовки не проставлены. Если послать запрос через `fetch($0.href, {mode: 'no-cors'})`, тор-браузер получает весь файл, что видно в devtools на вкладке Сеть. Однако, при сохранении запроса из devtools в har-формате, там оказывается только первый мегабайт ответа сервера.

Как сохранить ответ сервера полностью?
А может есть способ сохранить ip при переходе по ссылке?

Использую обычный Tor Browser.

Comment: А если идти по пути тор - дополнительный прокси сервер - цель ?

Comment: @Mike, ну предположим. А как настроить?

Comment: Ну это зависит от того как вы его используете. Если тор например в прозрачном режиме, т.е. не требует указания его в качестве прокси в настройках браузера, то в браузере ставиться любой прокси и к нему будет идти путь через тор. Иначе надо копаться видимо в настройках самого тор и как то задавать конкретную выходную точку (сам протокол позволяет, позволяют ли реализации я не в курсе)

Comment: @Mike, у меня обычный Tor Browser Bundle.